# Navigating to the specific screen when app is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

There are alarms of three categories for me., where each of them will be navigating to their respective specified screens.Here when I am broadcasting showing local notification when alarm triggers.Here I am maintaining an intent extra to which screen should it navigate.Thereby when I am calling an activity to navigate in pending intent.,onNewIntent method is handling the screen navigation.

```
  private void showNotification(Context context) {
           ...

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("fragmentname", "firstCategory");
           ...
     }
```

//Main Activity's onNewIntent method

```
 @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            String screenName = intent.getStringExtra("fragmentname");
            if (screenName != null && screenName.equalsIgnoreCase("firstCategory")) {
     moveToFirstCategoryScreen();
              }
}
```

Navigation currently works fine until the app is either in the foreground or being in recently opened apps.but once if I am removing from recently opened apps, when a notification arrives it is not navigating to the particular screen.

On debug, I figured out that the activities' onNewIntent method is not calling.

How could I handle screen navigation when the app is in the background.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 06/04/2018**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = MainActivity.this;
        onNewIntent(getIntent());
}     


 @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                super.onNewIntent(intent);
                String screenName = intent.getStringExtra("fragmentname");
                if (screenName != null && screenName.equalsIgnoreCase("firstCategory")) {
         moveToFirstCategoryScreen();
                  }
    }

 private void moveToFirstCategoryScreen() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstCategory.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent);

    }


    }
```

In my Alarm Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getName();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();
        showNotification(context);
        }



 private void showNotification(Context context) {
               ...

         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("fragmentname", "firstCategory");
               ...
         }
}
```

Manifest:

```
...

  <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             />

...
```

Comment: Are you opening the app by clicking app launch icon or notification

Comment: on notification click

Answer (score 0):

Write below code inside onCreate() method of your MainActivity class.

```
onNewIntent(getIntent())
```

Comment: When first time any activity open that time onNewIntent() method not calling.

when activity is already opened then it's onNewIntent() method will call where just intent would be update.

But that activity should be singleTask